# Pandas call function for each row of a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
CUR_MONTH   PREV_MONTH
Jan            Dec
Dec             Nov
Nov            Oct
```

I need to call a function that accepts two parameters CUR_MONTH and PREV_MONTH. How can I call the function in a loop for each row of the dataframe?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Pandas has a lot of built-in functions where you can specify the axis.

Answer (score 0):

This would return your function's row level calculation as a column in your dataframe

```
for index, row in your_dataframe.iterrows():
   row_level_calculation = your_function(row['CUR_MONTH'], row['PREV_MONTH'])
   your_dataframe.loc[index, 'new_column_with_calculation'] = row_level_calculation
```

For speed, you could also avoid the loop by setting up your function like this.

```
def row_calculation(row):
    current_month = row['CUR_MONTH']
    previous_month = row['PREV_MONTH']
    generic_calculation = concat(current_month + previous_month)
    return(generic_calculation)

your_dataframe['new_column_with_calculation'] = your_dataframe.apply(row_calculation, axis = 1)
```